# Connection battery charger IC to battery protection

Tags: battery-charging, batteries, over-voltage-protection

I'm trying to design a battery charger with protection for 2 cells in series. I'll try to work with this charger:

[image]

together with this protection IC:

[image]

Sorry for the dumb question but I'm quite new in this field. What are PB+ and PB- terminals?

Comment: what does the datasheet say? ... probably `protected battery`

Comment: It doesn't define them. Do you think that PB- is just the main ground? In that case, VSS should not be ground, right?

Comment: I think that PB- is the negative terminal of the battery pack ... the protection IC prevents charging faults ... you probably need a different charger IC because there is no available connection to the battery midpoint  ... treat the two cells and the HY2120 as a two terminal black box

Comment: Ok, I get. So HY2120 is to be used in one of those 2S batteries packs that have a 2 jumper plug (instead 3).